# Random ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, csrf

I get random `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` errors on my production server. There are no AJAX requests, all forms are created with Rails helpers (so they do include hidden field with authenticity_token).

The problem appears randomly on random forms.

In my `ApplicationController` I have `before_action :expires_now`. Could that be a problem? I added this because my users often click 'back' in their browsers and I didn't want them having cached results.

My session_store.rb initializer looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'
```

If that makes any difference I use Devise with `timeoutable` module and its `config.timeout_in` set to `1.hour`.

I'm using Rails 5.0.1.

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :not_authorized
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  add_flash_types :success, :warning, :danger, :info
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_current_user
  before_action :set_cache_headers

  def after_sign_out_path_for(_user)
    tasks_path
  end

  def not_authorized
    flash[:warning] = 'You are not authorized to execute this action.'
    redirect_to tasks_path
  end

  private

  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end

  def set_cache_headers
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'
  end
end
```